# Using GraphQL strictly as a query language

Tags: rest, graphql, jersey-2.0, graphql-java

I think that my problem is a common one, and I'm weighing the costs and benefits of GraphQL as a solution.

I work on a product whose data is stored by a monolithic CRUD-based REST API.  We have components of our application expose a search interface for data, and of course need some kind of server-side support for making requests for that data.  This could include sorting, filtering, choosing fields, etc.  There are, of course, more traditional ways of providing these functions in a REST context, like query parameter add-ons for endpoints, but it would be cool to try out GraphQL in this context to build a foundation for expanding its use for querying a bit.

GraphQL exposes a really nice query language for searching on data, and ultimately allows me to tailor the language of search specifically to my domain.  However, I'm not sure if there is a great way to leverage the IDL without managing a separate server altogether.

Take the following Java Jersey API Proof-of-Concept example:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/api/v1/search")
  public Response search(QueryIDL query) throws IOException {
    final SchemaParser schemaParser = new SchemaParser();

    TypeDefinitionRegistry typeDefinitionRegistry = // load schema
    RuntimeWiring runtimeWiring = // wire up data-fetching classes
    SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator();
    GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema =
        schemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(typeDefinitionRegistry, runtimeWiring);
    GraphQL build = GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build();

    ExecutionResult executionResult = build.execute(query.toString());

    return Response.ok(executionResult.getData()).build();
  }
```

I am just planning to take a request body into my Jersey server that looks exactly like the request that would be sent to a GraphQL server.  I'm then leveraging some library support to interpret and execute the request for data.

Without really thinking too much about everything that could go wrong, it looks like a client would be able to use this API similar to the way they would use a GraphQL server, except that I don't need to necessarily manage a separate server just to facilitate my search requirements.

Does it seem valuable, or silly, to use the GraphQL IDL in an endpoint-based context like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from not needing to rebuild the schema or the `GraphQL` instance on each request (there are cases where you may want to rebuild the `GraphQL` instance, but your case is not the one), this is pretty much the canonical way of using it.
It is rather uncommon to keep a separate server for GraphQL, and it usually gets introduced exactly the way you described - as just another endpoint next to your usual REST endpoints. So your usage is legit - not silly at all :)

Btw, I'm not sure what would `QueryIDL` be... the query is just a string. No need for a special class.

Comment: Much appreciated!  Yea, I work at a pretty small company, with very little GraphQL exposure, so I wanted a sanity check more than anything, given how much I see the phrase "GraphQL Server" fly around.  I appreciate it!